# Template content is not being injected into slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use slots to inject content from a parent component to its child, but Vue keeps rendering the default content, not parsing the content sent from its parent.

This is the code of the parent component, which in turn is a child of a global component:

```
let parentComponent = {
    template: `
        <div>
            <child-component>
                <template v-slot:action>Close</template>
                <template v-slot:element>Modal</template>
            </child-component>
        </div>        
    `,
    components: {
        'child-component': childComponent 
    }
};
```

And here is its child component, where I want to pass content:

```
let childComponent = {
    template: `
         <button>
            <slot name="action">Open</slot>
            <slot name="element">Window</slot>
          </button>       
    `,
};
```

The button is still displaying the default content: "Open Window"

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the rest of the content, just in case it helps:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VueJS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <vue-directives></vue-directives>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="components/slotDirective/slotDirectiveSubcomponent.js"></script>
    <script src="components/slotDirective/slotDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="components/VueDirectives.js"></script>
    <script>
        let vue = new Vue({
            el: '#app'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And VueDirectives.js:

```
Vue.component('vue-directives', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
            <parentComponent/>
        </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            title: "VueJS directives",
        }
    },
    components: {
        parentComponent 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me the render function, because I tried it and it's working

Comment: @Quantumass I'm not sure what you mean with the render function. I'm very new to Vue.js (starting from yesterday). So, I've added the rest of the code: index.html and a global component which in turn comprises the two components I previously added here.

Comment: this one "-the global component which in turn comprises the two components "

Comment: @Quantumass: I've added it too to the post.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI or a CDN?  There is some inconsistent component registration and naming that mixes both types, some of which would not work with a CDN.

Comment: @Dan: I'm using a CDN to load Vue.js, but following your advice, I'll try loading it locally

Comment: That won't help unless you mean starting a CLI project.  The difference I refer to is between CLI vs CDN syntax, but not between CDN and a local script.

Comment: @Dan: Just now I've tried loading vue.js locally but the problem persists

Comment: @Dan: sorry, I didn't notice it. I haven't used the CLI to create the project. I just created a new folder with the index.html file through my IDE, and started a local development server I installed via npm called live-server, in order to test it.

Comment: No worries.  Actually, your code seems to work fine as is:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/nwp93kcL/  Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: @Dan: yes I also tried pasting it on jsFiddle and it worked too. I don't know what's making it to fail in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that slots are designed for this. If you are just changing the text of a button passing props into the parentComponent is how i would go about it. E.g.

```
<parentComponent buttonText="some text or bind with a data value or computed prop"/>
```

see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Using slots... If you are experimenting try this, a reusable dialog box that you can pop in anywhere and control the content. E.g.

```
// myDialog
<v-dialog>
    <slot>Here you can put what you want</slot>
</v-dialog>
```

And to use:

```
<myDialog>
    <template>
        <myContent /> Or just put content here without another component
    </template>
</myDialog>
```

Comment: I really wanted to use slots just as an excercise on how to inject content from a parent component into its child, despite this example is so simple it can be achieved more properly with another functionality I haven't covered yet.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. I don't know the reason, but it wasn't working either if I loaded Vue.js from a CDN, or if I manually downloaded it locally, as a single file.

Then I finally tried installing it from **npm**, and loading Vue.js in `node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js`, and this way it works. I assume otherwise Vue.js does not comply with all its functionality.